# How to save High Score : Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to show high score from previous score. two separate texts , one will display previous score and another will display high score. I am fetching score from another scene and displaying it in score scene.

Here the script for previous score applied in Score Scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HscoreHard : MonoBehaviour {

    //for previous score
    public int previousScore;
    public Text displayscore;

    //for highscore
    public int highscore;
    public Text displayHScore

    void Start () {
        previousScore=PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelHardScore");
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    }

    void Update () {
        displayscore.text = "" + previousScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what happens? and the problem is

Comment: Can you include your code for saving the previous score?

Comment: I agree, the informations provided are not sufficient. By the way (as a side note), that PlayerPrefs.Save() is useless, because you are not updating the PlayerPrefs in that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i undersdtand what you want.
You can use "DontDestroyOnLoad" if you want your previous score.

As for updating the highscore you will do something like.

```
if(previousScore > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelHardScore"))
{
 PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelHardScore" , previousScore);
 PlayerPrefs.Save ();
}
```

DontDestroyOnLoad doc:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: To make use of "DontDestroyOnLoad", the gameobject must not be under any parented object that would be destroyed. If not, it will be destroyed along with the parent. Therefore, it will be best to create a "World" object and make it "DontDestroyOnLoad" and a singleton so that you can obtain whatever reference you need.

Comment: Actually i did this highscore thing sometime ago, and i remember i made it very simple. Ill try to update my answer when i have time and let you know how i did it.
But if he has a "GameManager" Gameobject he could perfectly use dont destroy.

Comment: I think the easiest would be "GameObject.Find ("go").getComponent <HscoreHard>()"